# Probability of getting a second ball that is numbered $3$

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: A bucket contains $4$ balls numbered $0$ through $3$. One ball is randomly selected from the bucket and not replaced. All balls with nonzero numbers less than that of the selected ball are also removed from the bucket. Then the second ball is selected from the remaining balls. What is the probability that the second ball is numbered $3$?
 I think I have to the use the conditional probability. So the probability of selecting any ball is $\frac{1}{4}$ is what I am going with. I also think I have to find the probability of getting the other balls when ball $0$,$1$,$2$, or $3$ is selected first. I think I have to multiply $\frac{1}{4}$ by $\frac{1}{3}$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ to solve this. Am I right? Need some assistance please

Comment: Never mind:  non-zero balls are removed.

Comment: @GrahamKemp the zero ball remains in the bucket in that case

Comment: @GrahamKemp I get zero for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just go through the different options:

The options for the second ball being 3 are:

First ball 0, second ball 3: $\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{3}$

First ball 1, second ball 3: same

First ball 2, second ball 3 (1 gets removed as well): $\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{2}$

Total: $\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{7}{24}$

Comment: when you same for first ball $1$ is it $\frac{1}{4}$ times $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @LadyT Yes, 1/4 chance for picking 1, and 1/3 for picking 3 after that, since nothing else gets removed

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your approach works well.   Denoting $F,S$ as first and second ball numbers, we just apply the Law of Total Probability, then count the balls left in the bucket for each case.

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(S=3) ~&=~ \mathsf P(S=3, F=0)+\mathsf P(S=3, F=1)+\mathsf P(S=3, F=2)+\mathsf P(S=3, F=3) \\ &=~ \tfrac 14(\tfrac{1}{\lvert\{1,2,3\}\rvert}+\tfrac{1}{\lvert\{0,2,3\}\rvert}+\tfrac{1}{\lvert\{0,3\}\rvert}+\tfrac{0}{\lvert\{0\}\rvert})\\[1ex] &= \tfrac 14(\tfrac 13+\tfrac 13+\tfrac 12+0)\end{align}$